# o input esta dentro da tag fildset, mas está cortando a linha

Tags: css, css3, input

[image: o input esta dentro da tag fildset, mas esta cortando a linha]

```
input {      
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o corpo da pergunta para descrever o problema também. O título é mais um resumo que servirá para organização da comunidade. Aproveite quando for [edit] e adicione o código HTML também, mas antes faça o [tour].

Comment: Provavelmente a largura dos `input` está ultrapassando a área onde eles estão. Tente adicionar um `max-width: 95%;` nesse css que vc informou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente voce definiu a width como 100% entao tente adicionar:

```
input {
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

E se ainda nao usa um reset:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta.

Comment: eu sei que nao responde mas nao tenho como responder sem mais detalhes e nao posso comentar.

Comment: Então aguarde ter reputação suficiente para fazer comentários.

Comment: E como consigo reputacao?

Comment: Fazendo perguntas ou respondendo, respeitando as regras. À medida que vc participa, vc ganha reputação.

Comment: editei reconsidere o voto.

Comment: Vou reconsiderar pra te estimular. Procure responder sem se basear em suposições. A pergunta requer mais informações para uma boa resposta.

Comment: Pior que nem sei como cancela rs.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite. É normal esse tipo de coisa acontecer, principalmente com inputs. Normalmente, nós temos que definir o estilo dele na mão, para ficar tanto estéticamente melhor, quanto nas questão de bugs e etc... No seu caso, é só diminuir a largura do elemento para a que melhor se adaptar ao seu gosto.

- Atente-se que ao alterar o atributo INPUT, todos terão as mesmas dimensões.

sendo assim, talvez, isso resolva seu problema:

```
input {      
font-size: 16px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
position: relative;
width: 90%; /* Esta será a alteração que fará a diferença */
}
```